# For anyone wondering about Daniil

Tags: discussion, user-accounts, users

**---content from him below, approved by CM in TL to post.**

It’s Daniil from Travel.

My accounts were destroyed by a CM so I had to go.

Please post this message from me on meta:

Hello Travel community, Daniil here. I enjoyed contributing to this site. I am sorry, but I have to go. It’s not my choice, but my accounts were destroyed by a CM. I will return by mid-2021. I hope you appreciated my contributions and my community work.

A new person has to be found the lead the photo competition, I wish the new person the best of luck. Thanks to the moderators, especially Willeke for guiding me through flagging posts, I finally earnt marshal (raise 500 helpful flags) today :).

Thanks to all the community and especially moderators for their support and guidance.

Good luck to the community, I’ll check in every now and again and take a look at all the photo competition photos ;).
I will miss you all.

All the best

---

Daniil

Comment: All the best Daniil. I’m sure everyone looks forward to seeing you back and contributing again.

Comment: What is a CM? Excuse my ignorance

Comment: @Ulkoma Community Managers. Us mods are volunteers, they're a level up and get paid ;) https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-are-the-community-team-and-what-do-they-do

Comment: @MarkMayoSupportsMonica thanks

Comment: *My accounts were destroyed by a CM so I had to go* - there is more to this, surely?

Comment: @Midavalo https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/338033/149926

Comment: Which is why he'll be returning in mid-2021.

Comment: @MarkMayoSupportsMonica wow I had no idea!

Comment: I would have assumed they were 10 years older than that from online interaction. That's really sad.

Comment: Life's long for communities, 2021 will be here in the blink of an eye. And you will be welcome back!

Comment: Maybe I've misunderstood the rules but reading https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/338033/under-age-users-could-they-just-be-suspended-until-of-age it looks to me like Daniil could register an account using a parent's email address, and then use it without any problems so long as he never posts any identifying info such as real name anywhere? The problem seems to be having a child's personally identifying info on the database rather than any outright ban on children posting here?

Comment: This is a very mature response. I hardly realized Daniil was underage and it feels incredibly unfair to him. I cannot believe there wasn't a less "nuclear" option like visiting SE under the parents' supervision, or getting their written permission to store their child's personal data on SE, or something along these lines. Thanks Daniil for your contributions and we hope to see you back.

Comment: @undercat to be fair, it's not SE's fault here, it's the law. They can't hold ANY PII (Personally Identiable Info) on a minor.

Comment: I'm sorry to see you go, @Daniil. And I'd be delighted to have you return.

Comment: @MarkMayoSupportsMonica they can as long as the parents agree. They could have added this option somehow.

Comment: @NeanDerThal an employee said that's [*"not worth the effort for any site not targeted at children"*.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/338033/under-age-users-could-they-just-be-suspended-until-of-age#comment1124878_338035) It seems a bit weird because there are many sites that aren't aimed at children but are used by them, but I guess the employees have bigger fish to fry. I mean there's a common denominator in the user names here, that eats up resources, I guess.

Comment: What is "in TL"?

Comment: @AzorAhai 'Teacher's Lounge' - it's the moderators' private chat room. Requested permission from a CM in there to post the content here.

Answer (score 9):

I am really disappointed to hear this news, and I was genuinely surprised to hear it was due to Daniil's age, and like many others I have tried to come up with a solution that would have allowed them to stay here and continue contributing (although clearly that's already been a discussion on MSE that doesn't need to be repeated here).

I wish Daniil all the best for the future, and look forward to having them back here when they are considered "old enough" (even while I'd take Daniil over some less mature but older individuals I have interacted with over the years in SO/SE!)

All the best Daniil, be seeing you soon!