# Announcing my return to Travel.SE

Tags: discussion

it's Daniil, **ex-user (89966)**. Most of you will probably know me. I was an active contributor to Travel.SE and a few other SE sites till I got destroyed on 11th November on 2019 on all SE sites due to the fact I was under 16 and based in an EU country (UK).

- [For anyone wondering about Daniil](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6398/for-anyone-wondering-about-daniil)

Can I just say thanks everyone for all your responses to the post above and thank you to Mark Mayo for posting it. I read all your comments, thank you for your kind words.

**So, what happened?**

It is 11th November 2019, I am chatting in the *You are Here* chat and then I leave to get dinner. I come back to find all my chat messages replaced with my user number instead of my username.

I try to post a message and it says I am not logged in. I go to the main Travel.SE site to log in and find I am logged out. I try to log in and it says I have no account.

I check my email and find an email from a CM explaining the situation. I ask the CM several times to leave a message in the Travel.SE chat but this is ignored.

Since I was destroyed I have still been checking Travel.SE and other SE sites several times a week because I miss the community.

**What has changed?**

SO's terms of service:

> **You must be at least 13 years old to access or use the Network or Services, including without limitation to complete a Stack Overflow account registration.** By accessing or using the Services or the Network in any manner, you represent and warrant that you are at least 13 years of age. If you are under 13 years old, you may not, under any circumstances or for any reason, access or use the Services or Network in any manner, and may not provide any personal information to or on the Services or Network (including, for example, a name, address, telephone number or email address).
>
> **If you are located within the European Union, you must be at least 16 years old to access or use the Network or Services**, including without limitation to complete a Stack Overflow Account Registration. By accessing or using the Services or the Network in any manner, you represent and warrant that you are at least 16 years of age. If you are under 16 years old, you may not, under any circumstances or for any reason, access or use the Services or Network in any manner, and may not provide any personal information to or on the Services or Network (including, for example, a name, address, telephone number or email address).

I am under 16 and was based in an EU country since then the UK has officially left the EU on January 31st so I am only required to be 13 which I am.

And, since the UK's COPPA Children's Online Privacy Protection Act is set to 13 I can return to SE. I emailed SE to ask whether I can return but I received no response even with two follow up emails.

I  miss this site too much now and I say no reason why I can't be on this site now. I have sent an email to SE and to the CM who destroyed me asking for re-association of all my posts and most likely everything will be ok.

:)

---

Daniil

Comment: For reference: https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6398/for-anyone-wondering-about-daniil?rq=1

Comment: For curiosity, would you mind posting the email you received from the CM?

Comment: @gparyani the initial email informing me of the ban?

Comment: Yes, that would be very nice.

Comment: @gparyani https://pastebin.com/uzYGfqtc

Comment: @DaniilManokhin have you asked the CM if you can have your old acc back?

Comment: Hey, something good came out of Brexit!

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder yes I did, no response yet

Comment: @MichaelHampton :)

Comment: I would just point out that the UK's minimum age for digital services has been 13 since September of 2017, so there was never any legal need to delete your account.  So, @MichaelHampton the fact that anything good has come out of Brexit is nonetheless due only to Stack Exchange's heavy-handed, ignorant interpretation of GDPR.

Comment: @phoog I know, hopefully I can get my posts re-associated soon

Comment: @MichaelHampton Not really, all EU law still continues to apply to the UK during the whole transition period (11 months, maybe more again?), so nothing has legally changed. But as phoog says, if SE thinks it actually matters, so be it.

Comment: @TooTea EU law continues to apply in the UK, but the terms of service do not make reference to EU law.  They only say "in the European Union."  It's clear to me that whoever wrote them did not talk to a European lawyer, but that's beside the point: the EU age limit does not apply to someone in the UK because the terms of service apply that age limit only to people "in the European Union."  For the same reason, the limit does not apply to people in other non-EU countries where the GDPR is in force.

Comment: @phoog Yeah, the ToS are again a great show of ignorance of SE for anything outside the US.

Comment: Perhaps you've noticed it already, but in case you have not, there is a question about this on [Law.SE]: [Will Stack Exchange EU terms still apply to Britain now that BREXIT has finished?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/48851/333)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Welcome Back Daniil!

Really happy to hear that you're back, and I'm looking forward to seeing your valuable contributions once again.  As I wrote on the previous Travel Meta post regarding your sudden disappearance, I was disappointed and felt the reasoning was a bit harsh, so I'm glad you've been given this opportunity to come back.

Glad to hear we're seeing you sooner than we all expected.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome :)

Answer (score 6):

I'll second that - welcome back Daniil!

While it'd be nice to have your posts reassociated, you're not your prior posts. Moving forward is a better strategy than looking to the past.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome. Welcome. And again: welcome!